# The web service long time cost process raises timeout in Client

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a process it takes a long time to finish and of course, it can write a response a long time after the call.

```
public void aHugeProcess()
{
var collection=GetAllPendingData();
foreach (DataRow current in collection)
 {
  dojob(current);
 }

//As you understand until coming here client already throws timeout exception!!
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(encoding.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hashTable));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

}
```

And after all, I added this update. And I think now keep-alive will keep client updated and never let it drop the connection BUT it throws timeout exception again:

```
public void aHugeProcess()
    {

HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout = 20000 max = 1000");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = -1;

    var collection=GetAllPendingData();
    foreach (DataRow current in collection)
     {
      dojob(current);
     }

    //As you understand until coming here client already throws timeout exception!!
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(encoding.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hashTable));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
```

Now I decided to make a TRICK. I write a meanless space character to response in each loop iteration. **HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" ");**  :) ok. it works. Because of response stream will have a data in timeout limits. All is working well. But I feel not comfortable with it. cause of it is trick not the design.

```
foreach (DataRow current in collection)
         {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" ");
    dojob(current);
         }
```

So could you help me to have the best practices and correct solutions?

Comment: If you know that the huge process takes so long that it causes timeouts, is HTTP really the best method of communication between your client and server? Could you instead have the "client" deliver a file to the "server", which triggers a scheduled job on the "server" to run the huge process and deliver a file with the results to the "client"? I appreciate that there may be constraints which prevent you using this approach (you don't say whether the client code is under your control, or whether it's running within your network or out there on the internet somewhere)

Comment: If you must use HTTP, maybe your web service could put all the input data into some kind of data store and return a URL to the client from which it can retrieve the results at some point in the future, and have the huge process run off the critical path by something completely separate from your web service (e.g. a windows service / daemon / scheduled job) which reads the input data from the data store and makes the results available at the returned URL. Of course, this only works if the client understands that they need to wait a while before attempting to get the results.

Comment: You are very correct @sbridewell But problem is Client already designed with HTTP and it has many more other functionality already. This is a new method and now it is long time cost process. And I don't have chance to change client design or create another kind of client for specific this method. So Yes I have to find solution in this technologies :(

Comment: And you second offer is very correct again @sbridewell Maybe I can go like PUB/SUB mechanism for this huge process. just fire and forget and check the result after its ready.

Comment: A further thought... if the client machine is also capable of acting as a web server, you could implement a webhook - when the huge process is complete on the server, the server makes a request to a URL originally supplied by the client, and that request contains the URL where the results of the huge process can be found. Solves the problem of the client knowing how long to wait before requesting the results. Of course this might not be possible within the constraints of what's already been designed / built on the client side, but worth considering.